# Is the probability of variable independence = 0?

Tags: probability, random

I understand the concept of independence to be dichotomous- events are either independent or dependent. And while there are infinitely many ways for events to be dependent and only one way to be independent, independent events are still likely and 'common'.

However, if rho is a continuous measure of (linear independence), it is thus that P(rho=0) is 0.

So if the probability of rho being exactly zero is zero, then does it follow that the probability of two random variables being independent is also zero?

Comment: Before you can speak of the "probability" of two random variables being independent, you must first have a probability distribution defined on the space of pairs of random variables.

Comment: Probably one could show that in several senses, the set of bivariate cdf $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ for which the marginals are independent is a "small" subset of all the bivariate cdf.